# Public transportation from Dallas DFW airport to Downtown

Tags: public-transport, layovers, dfw

I'll have a long layover in Dallas (~12 hours).
I was hoping to visit the downtown. Is it feasible?

I was looking for public transportation. The [airport website](http://dfwairport.com/transport/public/index.php) provides a list of options but does not mention the travel time.

I would like to know how long it takes from DFW to downtown with the different transportation services.

Comment: Google Maps shows several options with travel times ranging from about 1 to 2 hours: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Dallas%2FFort+Worth+International+Airport,+3200+E+Airfield+Dr,+DFW+Airport,+TX+75261,+United+States/Dallas,+TX,+USA/@32.8381111,-97.065977,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x864c2a660d222aa7:0x73323f5e067d201c!2m2!1d-97.040335!2d32.899809!1m5!1m1!1s0x864c19f77b45974b:0xb9ec9ba4f647678f!2m2!1d-96.8004511!2d32.7801399!3e3

Comment: A taxi ride to [downtown Dallas](http://www.downtowndallas.org/) is a flat $45, and DFW gives the same rate to the [Dallas West End](http://www.dallaswestend.org/) shopping/entertainment. At that rate, renting a car might be cheaper and more convenient than either transit or taxi.

Comment: [DART](http://www.dart.org/), the public transit agency in the Dallas area, it extending their orange line to DFW. It is planned to open August 18, 2014. Not sure what the travel time will be when it's completed though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DFW is a fair distance away from the city, so you'll definitely need a good chunk of time to get there and back, especially using public transportation.  But 12 hours should be enough.

Google Maps has excellent coverage of the public transportation options in Dallas, and shows that to get from DFW to the Dallas Museum of Arts in down town takes [nearly two hours](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Dallas%2FFort+Worth+International+Airport,+3200+East+Airfield+Drive,+DFW+Airport,+TX+75261&daddr=N+Harwood+St&hl=en&sll=32.794201,-96.805944&sspn=0.051011,0.104628&geocode=FeEC9gEdMUg3-imnKiINZipMhjEcIH0GXj8ycw%3BFQZP9AEdEPA6-g&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=ltm&t=m&z=12&start=0), depending on the time of day and which route you take.

With a 12 hour layover, plus 4 hours commuting, and wanting to return 2 hours before your flight, that would give you roughly 6 hours to see down town--so it's doable.

If you want more time, you might consider seeing something closer to the airport.

Answer (score 4):

The DART light rail orange line now runs to DFW.  It takes about an hour from the airport station to downtown. To get to the airport station, take the airtrain inside security to terminal A, or if you arrive international, the much slower terminal link bus at the curb on the upper level.  Buy a $5 day pass.
The downtown stations are within walking distance of plenty of touristy stuff.